# Optimal clustering with optimal number of clusters as well as max and min cluster size constraints

Tags: optimization, clustering

I need to cluster $N$ data points.

I don't know the number of clusters to be formed. It needs to be found optimally.

Also, there is maximum and minimum cluster size constraints, where $C_{\max}$ is the maximum size that one cluster can get and $C_{\min}$ is the minimum size that one cluster must get.

The coordinates of the $N$ data points are stored in a matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times N}$, $D$ is a matrix of $N$ rows and each row has two elements defining the $x-$axis and $y-$axis coordinates. However, $D$ can be expressed in any convenient form, for example, $D\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times 2}$ or $D\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$ (where the coordinates are expressed as a complex number: $x+iy$)

How can I formulate this as a mathematical optimization problem and solve it efficiently?

Data points can be uniformly distributed over a 2D plan of any given size.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139830/755, https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6217/2415, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4125370/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1.** There are various clustering algorithms depending on different requirements. You can employ [$k$-means clustering method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Algorithms) since it is fast, simple, and popular.

**Answer 2**. If you do not know the number of clusters, employ [Elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)#:%7E:text=In%20cluster%20analysis%2C%20the%20elbow,number%20of%20clusters%20to%20use.). That is, first cluster the data for $k = 1$. Then cluster the data with $k = 2$, then $k = 3$ and so on. Initially, the cost of the clustering will decrease rapidly with increase in $k$. Once the $k$-means cost starts to appear constant with increase in $k$; that value of $k$ is the desired number of clusters.

**Answer 3.** When there are constraints on the size of clusters, the problem is (informally) known as the [balanced clustering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_clustering) or capacitated clustering problem. The Wikipedia article does contain a few links of its implementation. This is a [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270280805_Balanced_K-Means_for_Clustering) for the balanced $k$-means problem. You might have to do some more research on this topic to find the perfect answer as per your requirement.

---

*Note:* The clustering problem that minimizes the $k$-means objective is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. Therefore, you can expect to find an optimal solution to your problem in polynomial time.

Comment: thanks. The first two answers are very well known to me. None of those actually fulfil my requirements. I need a solution that combines Answer1 and Answer2.

Comment: @dipaknarayanan They are already combined. I do not understand what are you are asking.

Comment: how are they combined? If I follow Answer1, I get $k$ number of clusters with different sizes. When I follow Elbow method, I get the optimal number of clusters. Lets say I then apply Answer1 with $k$ equal to the optimal number of clusters that I get using elbow method. Will these $k$ clusters follow the constraints that I have for min and maximum cluster sizes?

Comment: @dipaknarayanan Let us forget Answer 1 since it might not satisfy cluster constraints. Now, we want to combine A2 and A3. You just need to run A3 for different values of $k$. And when $k$-means cost starts to appear constant; that is your desired value of $k$..

Comment: @dipaknarayanan Technically speaking, there is nothing like "optimal value of $k$" since the $k$-means cost always decreases with increasing value of $k$. For example: set $k = n$. The optimal clustering would assign single point to each cluster and the $k$-means cost would be $0$. And, that does not make sense for unconstrained version

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use [agglomerative clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering), merging clusters until  you get something whose size is in the acceptable range.

If you prefer to use optimization, another possible approach is to define an objective function $\Phi$ that measures the  quality of a clustering, as a sum of  two terms:
$$\Phi = L + P$$
where $L$ measures how tightly coupled the clusters are (it might be any standard objective function for clustering, e.g., sum of pairwise squared distances between pairs of points in the same cluster, [as in k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Description)), and $P$ is a penalty term that measures whether the cluster sizes are as desired (e.g., $P = \max(\ell-s,0)^2 + \max(s-u,0)^2$, where $s$ is the size of an individual cluster and $\ell,u$ are the desired minimum and maximum cluster sizes).  This is basically applying the [penalty method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) for constrained optimization.  As an alternative, you could use the [barrier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function) instead of the penalty method, which would involve replacing $P$ with a barrier function that becomes infinite once the cluster size is too big or too small (e.g., $P = b_u(x) + b_{-\ell}(-x)$ where $b_u(x) = -\log(u-x)$ if $x < u$ or $b_u(x) = +\infty$ if $x \ge u$).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Looks very interesting. Would you please provide a full mathematical formulation with objective and constraints. Is it easy to solve?